# How to check input box value is empty when adding value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used following jquery to add value to my input box,

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#name').val('some text');
});
```

Now i need to check and show clear button if text added to input. I have tried following code. But it's need to click on input box to work.

```
$('#name').blur(function(){
       if ($(this).val()) {
          $(".input-clear").show();
       }
       else {
          $(".input-clear").hide();
       }
    });
});
```

How can i show the button if text added to input box correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you put your code in `$(document).ready(function() {`, secondly have CSS for `.input-clear` to hide the button initially. And then check if value is entered and is not just blank, based on that `show/hide` the button:

```js
$('#name').on('input change', function() {
  var valueEntered = $(this).val();
  valueEntered.trim().length > 0 ? $(".input-clear").show() : $(".input-clear").hide();
});

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  $('#name').val('some text').trigger('change');
});
```

```css
.input-clear {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='btn'>Button</button>
<input type='text' id='name' />
<button class='input-clear'>Clear</button>
```

Comment: This is working if i'm typing on text field. But i my case i'm using jquery to load text in to input box.

Comment: You mean text field is already populated with value, right?.. Have updated code.

Comment: instead of blur try change event on input box. if that does not work then manually trigger change on input box  $('#input').val(''your value").trigger('change');

Comment: @ManojYadav - Good point. Added on `change` and on `input` too.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a change-event which will be called whenever the input is changed by the user. To also make this fire when the input is changed programmatically, simply call `change` after you've updated the input.

```js
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#name').val('some text').change();
});

$('#name').change(function () {
  if ($(this).val().length) {
    $('.clear').show();
  } else {
    $('.clear').hide();
  }
});

$('.clear').click(function () {
  $('#name').val('').change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name"></input>
<button style="display: none;" class="clear">Clear</button>
<br/>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/w6ugt7cy/

```js
$('#btn').click(function(){
  $('#name').val('some text');
  $('button.clear').show();
});

$('button.clear').click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $('#name').val('');
});

$('#name').keyup(function(){
  if($(this).val().trim() === ''){
    $('button.clear').hide();
  } else {
    $('button.clear').show();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" />
<button style="display: none;" class="clear">Clear</button>
<br/>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Hope this will help you.